# Editable text box on MS Access 2010 - Behavior correct?

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, textbox

I have a continuous form which displays an overview/summary of my data. A user can select a row and click a button I created in the footer to open another form which has all the detail for that particular record and be able to edit it. This works fine. However I would also like for certain fields to be editable from the continuous form. I enabled two fields I would like users to edit directly (One is a combo box selection and the other a text box) When users click the combo box for any record it works fine and they can go back to the same record and select another value if they wish. All great but the text box behaves rather differently - The text box will allow the user to initially enter a value but after entry the box appears disabled and the only way to change the initial data entry is to go into the detail form which still works. Why can't users change the text box from the continuous form after an initial entry?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue!

There was a conditional filter on that particular field